# Filtering and removing the condition

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using the below formula and want to collect the data from the following columns but the last part of the formula I'm using is only collecting if the answer is 'Yes'. I want it to collect for both 'yes' and 'no' responses (or any response) whilst keeping the filtering the same as below.

```
=FILTER({'Form responses Original'!AM3:AM,'Form responses Original'!E3:E, 'Form responses Original'!B3:B, 'Form responses Original'!G3:G,'Form responses Original'!L3:M},UPPER('Form responses Original'!F3:F="yes"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then you no need `FILTER()` function. Just try-

```
={'Form responses Original'!AM3:AM,'Form responses Original'!E3:E, 'Form responses Original'!B3:B, 'Form responses Original'!G3:G,'Form responses Original'!L3:M}
```

Or with `FILTER()` like

```
=FILTER({'Form responses Original'!AM3:AM,'Form responses Original'!E3:E, 'Form responses Original'!B3:B, 'Form responses Original'!G3:G,'Form responses Original'!L3:M},UPPER('Form responses Original'!F3:F<>""))
```

Or can use `QUERY()` function.

Comment: Thank you! I knew I was overcomplicating this somewhere but wasn't sure how!